# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'

Tags: python, regex

My Code snipet:

```
compileObj = re.compile('\b%s\b'%word)
result = compileObj.search(sentence[j])
print result.groups()

word = foo
sentence = foo bar (foo) bar foo-bar foo_bar foo'bar bar-foo bar, foo
```

But the result's value is None and I am not able figure out why.

Kindly let me know if I am missing something very basic.

Comment: As per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) of `search`, it returns `None` when there are no matches

Comment: The last two lines of your code.... is that valid syntax?  This may lead to why you're not finding any matches in your search.

Comment: Did you control what was in fact `'\b%s\b'%word`. It is probably not what you expect...

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> sentence = "foo bar (foo) bar foo-bar foo_bar foo'bar bar-foo bar, foo"
>>> word = 'foo'
>>> compileObj = re.compile(r'\b%s\b' % re.escape(word))
>>> result = compileObj.search(sentence)
>>> print result.group()
foo
>>> print compileObj.findall(sentence)
['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo']
```

Possible misconceptions and the corresponding explanations:

- You need a raw string `r'\bfoo\b' to make python not interpret the special characters (in this example the backslash``) and pass them unchanged to the regular expression library.
- You probably want to `re.escape` the word in case it contains more regular expression special characters.
- `.search()` only finds the first match. To find all matches use `.findall()` or `.finditer()`